# Appending and printing list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append, empty-list

Ive tried to make a list in Python 3 where it appends and prints out all the numbers thats less than the userinput, but when the user types in 90 or more the list goes empty. Why?

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
num = int(input('Please enter a randome number: '))
a = 0
y = []
while (a < 11):
     if (x[a] < num):
    y.append(x[a])
#   print (x[a])
    a = a + 1
else:
    print (y)
    break
```

Comment: your indentation is all over the place. Have a look at my answer for proper indentation and for a better solution to the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this is much cleaner, proper indentation, and doesn't rely on sorted list:

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
num = int(input('Please enter a random number: '))

y = []
for item in x:
    if item < num:
        y.append(item)

print(y)
```

Comment: Thank you! It was cleaner and easier to understand!

Comment: No worries, happy to help @Hernes97

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clue what language this so this might be totally wrong, but you say you want it to print the numbers if they are less than 90.

You are doing `if (x[a] < num)` then append the data to y otherwise print y.

I think you mean

```
while (a < 11):
    if (x[a] < num):
        y.append(x[a])
    #   print (x[a])
        a = a + 1
print (y)
```

Like I say I don't know the language, but it looks like an indentation issue.

Comment: It's python 3. So instead of ending it in an else statement i should just do the if statement?

Comment: You want to create a list of numbers less that `num` and then print them, so I don't see why you need a else statement.  (Unless you want to stop creating the number the first time you see a number greater than `num`)